# My mouse wheel skips half the page

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

I have the "Mac OSX Lion" theme installed on my Ubuntu 12.04.1 computer.

I have this glitch with my scroll wheel, that when I try to scroll down the page,l it skips about 1/2 of it.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that you can fix this glitch by simply un-plugging your mouse for 10 seconds, then plugging it back in.

After you do that, it scrolls normally.

Comment: any idea of how can fix this without remove the mouse from PC? :)

Comment: Hold your mouse where it is and move your PC away from it. In all seriousness, pgrytdal's fix does work and is permanent.